# Is cookie in https secure?

Tags: security, cookies, https, session-cookies

I know cookies and session id are encrypted and then sent to client so that middle man cannot see the cookie value.

My question is, suppose I logged in a https site and leave the computer for some time. Then one of my friend quickly go to the browser's developer tool and get the cookies. Can he use that cookies to hack my account later?

If yes, how to develop the site so that he cannot hack my account even if someone get my cookie value and session id.

Comment: Few questions: 1) What type of data do you store in cookies? Are you talking about a "Remember me" / long-terme authentication cookie? - 2) Does your 'friend' has directly access to your computer or he is just in your local network?

Comment: 1) Lets say plain string is saved in cookies
2) Yes my 'friend' has direct access but lets us assume that he cannot access the private key.

Comment: If someone has ***physical access*** to your computer, then all bets are off. What stops them from simply going to the site you're still logged into and doing some mayhem directly; e.g. change your password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies on HTTPS are only secure if they either have the [secure flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) set or are served from an [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) domain.

Otherwise, a Man-In-The-Middle could intercept the cookie.

Say your site is example.com, and is only available over HTTPS, on which it sets cookies. Bob, your victim browses to foo.com over plain HTTP over an insecure network.

The Man-In-The-Middle, Mallory, could intercept a request to foo.com and inject

```
<img src="http://example.com" />
```

She then intercepts the request to example.com which contains the cookies - now Mallory has your victim's cookies to example.com and can log in as Bob, even though you only listen over HTTPS.

This is because the Same Origin Policy is less stringent when it comes to cookies.

Now what you're saying is that Bob keeps his machine logged in, and then Alice comes along later to steal his session.

You could do some [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) things and check that their user agent and [panopticlick fingerprint](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) are the same. This would thwart non-determined hackers.

Also, you could verify that their IP is the same IP that they logged in with. This will not protect hackers on the same network, such as when Bob and Alice work in the same office, however it would stop Alice going home then using the session details. Also beware of ISPs that use shared IPs (e.g. AOL) and ISPs that may vary the client IP address (e.g. 3/4G providers could, or when the user switches from mobile reception to WiFi).

Answer (score 2):

If your "friend" can access your browser, he can see the cookies, and use them to steal you sessions to whatever website you were connected.

HTTPS only protect the **communication** between your computer and the websites. Everything in your computer is available in plain text.